# When there is only one image, what is the meaning of Minibatchsize?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, batch-processing

I am reading the code provided by matlab. https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/rcnnobjectdetector.detect.html

When there is only one image as the input, why there is a parameter "MiniBatchSize"? How can we understand this?

This is the code

```
%Test the R-CNN detector on a test image.

img = imread('stopSignTest.jpg');

[bbox, score, label] = detect(rcnn, img, 'MiniBatchSize', 32);
```

Comment: The parameter is there no matter how many inputs you have. It doesn’t change meaning. It might not have any effect if you only have one input image, but that shouldn’t change the API, should it?

Answer (score 0):

With inference calls like "detect", MiniBatchSize is a declaration of how many images should be batched at a time for MxNxCxB input where B > 1. When the input number of images is not cleanly divisible by the MiniBatchSize, then the final batching in detect allows the remainder of images to pass through.

In this case, there is only one image so only one image flows through at inference time.